# Problema no jQuery de um MENU com duas <ul> 's

Tags: jquery, html

Estou tendo um problema com um Menu.

Acontece que quando a pessoa passa o mouse no link **Atendimento**, acontece um `dropdown`, o menu aparece, pois ele está com `display:none` e quando passa o mouse fica `display:block`.

Até então tudo bem, só que estou tendo um problema, preciso que isso aconteça com mais de uma `<ul>`. Só que apenas a 1° `<ul>` está recebendo esse efeito.

Quero que quando a pessoa passar o mouse sobre o link **Atendimento**, aconteça esse efeito nas 2 ou *mais* `<ul>` 's aí vou poder fazer como se fosse um `Mega Menu`.

Código do **Menu** | `HTML`:

```
                    <li>
                        <a href="blog.html">Atendimento</a>
                        <ul><!-- Primeiro | No caso o .first() -->
                            <li><a href="base.html">Base de Conhecimento</a></li>
                            <li><a href="blog.html">Nosso Blog</a></li>
                            <li><a href="contato.php">Fale conosco</a></li>
                            <li><a href="suporte.html">Suporte</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul><!-- Segundo | Não funciona -->
                            <li><a href="base.html">Base de Conhecimento</a></li>
                            <li><a href="blog.html">Nosso Blog</a></li>
                            <li><a href="contato.php">Fale conosco</a></li>
                            <li><a href="suporte.html">Suporte</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
```

Código do **Menu** | `jQuery`:

```
jQuery("#menu > li").hover(function() {
        jQuery(this).find("ul").first().slideDown(600);
    }, function() {
        jQuery(this).find("ul").first().slideUp(200);

    });

    jQuery("#menu li ul li").hover(function() {
        jQuery(this).find("ul").first().toggle(0);

    });

    jQuery("#menu li ul li").each(function() {
        if(jQuery(this).has("ul").length > 0) {
            jQuery(this).addClass("menu-arrow")
        }
    });
```

Acredito que o problema está no `.first()` = **primeiro (em português)**, no caso só funciona com a primeira `<ul>`, mas preciso que funcione com as 2 `<ul>`.

Obs: tentei remover o `.first()`, porém ele deixou todo o menu bugado. (Ainda sou iniciante)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme o modelo que você me passou pelo bate-papo, o seu segundo UL é filho do A, então o jquery teve que ser adaptado:

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li> <a href="blog.html">Atendimento</a>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="base.html">Base de Conhecimento</a></li>
            <li><a href="blog.html">Nosso Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="contato.php">Fale conosco</a></li>
            <li> <a href="suporte.html">Suporte
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="base.html">Base de Conhecimento</a></li>
                        <li><a href="blog.html">Nosso Blog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contato.php">Fale conosco</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="suporte.html">Suporte</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**jquery:**

```
$("#menu").find('li').hover(function () {
    $(this).children('ul').clearQueue().slideDown(600);
    $(this).children('a').children('ul').clearQueue().fadeIn(600);
}, function () {
    $(this).children('ul').slideUp(600);
    $(this).children('a').children('ul').fadeOut(600);
});

$("#menu").find('a').has( "ul" ).each(function() {
    $(this).addClass("menu-arrow");
});
```

Ou seja, todo o LI que tiver um filho UL e também todo LI que tiver um filho A que tem um filho UL, vão disparar os eventos, mostrando o UL e depois ocultando novamente.

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jaderw/p83s8zL6/7/

Comment: Sim, é que eu não coloquei o código todo, apenas a parte dos 2 `<ul>`. Esse seu código deixou meu menu bugado. Não funciona mais. Você também não colocou os IDS ex: `#menu li ul li`.

Comment: Agora funcionou, só que aconteceu um erro, o menu do dropdown também tem um submenu, agora ele não abre mais.

Comment: @AlexandreLopes Examine o código com atenção, note que todo o bloco de `<ul>` deve ficar dentro do `<li>` pai, nesse esquema que passei funciona em "infinitos" níveis.

Comment: Encontrei o problema, é que depois do `<li>` tem que ficar o `<ul>` e o que tinha era um `<a>`, você poderia colocar os IDS? Pra funcionar somente no menu. Do jeito que está funciona em qualquer lugar do site.

Comment: que elemento esta com o id #menu?

Comment: Não tá funcionando certo, pois até o submenu está com o efeito de cascata.

Comment: Não teria como somente poder adicionar o efeito em mais de 1 `<ul>` sem precisar mexer no HTML?

Comment: Tipo que o efeito também funcionasse no:  `#menu > li:nth-child(4) > ul:nth-child(3)`

Comment: desculpe não entendi como é esse seu menu, se você puder passar um fiddle com o código completo e original facilitaria muito

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16322/discussion-between-jader-and-alexandre-lopes).

Comment: seu jQuery parece ter um pequeno `bug`, quando passo o mouse no menu e depois tira o mouse ele fica com um bug na aparência do site. Veja quando passa o mouse: http://s2.postimg.org/c5bj4m1nd/Screenshot.png e quando tira o mouse: http://s2.postimg.org/ilkhupa6x/Screenshot2.png

Comment: Obs: Utilizando Google Chrome

Comment: Será se o problema é só no Navegador?

Comment: Ta com jeito de ser algum bug na renderização do navegador, pois o script só faz mostrar e ocultar com o hover, e se fosse o script o objeto inteiro iria ficar visível... tente trocar os efeitos de fadein para show e fadeout para hide veja se muda alguma coisa.

Comment: Sim, resolveu! @Jader edite sua resposta. Ficou 100% aqui. Eu nem estava utilizando o fade mesmo, eu até coloquei (0) no fade para não aparecer. :D

Comment: Então quem sabe era esse o problema (zero no fade)...

Comment: Hihihihi, não sei, só sei que agora está: `.show(0)` e `.hide(0)`

Comment: Eu tenho que remover? ou deixa com (0) mesmo ?

Answer (score 1):

A minha sugestao é fazer isso só com CSS.

```
ul  ul {
    display: none;
}

ul > li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/n6ty5jut/

Podia até fazer com animacao CSS:

```
ul  ul {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}

ul > li:hover ul {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/n6ty5jut/1/

Comment: Uauuu! Ficou interessante...

Comment: Não resolve só com CSS, pois tem alguns efeitos...

Comment: @AlexandreLopes quais? o que lhe falta?

Comment: É que tinha um submenu que não estava funcionando. E eu precisava que o jQuery adicionasse uma classe `menu-arrow`, só que deu certo com o @Jader, mais muito obrigado @Sergio por me ajudar sempre.